# Sort attribute values in admin with your own attributes

Tags: adminform, attribute-set

We have created a attribute with a lot of values and we don't want to use the position field. 
When we create a new product all of the options in the select component are random we want to arrange those by sorting by ABC.

How can we fix this in the admin in Magento

Update: august 25, 2014
Nobody?

Answer (score 2):

There are two main ways to do this.

**Method One: New Input Rendered**

In this method, you're only changing the input field in the Admin. If this field appears on the front-end or in custom code, it won't be sorted there.

- You'll want to update your attribute with a new `input_renderer` value, which points to a new model. Take a look at a similar example [here](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/adding-magento-attribute-with-custom-input-renderer/).
- You'll want to make sure you're model is extending the right Varien class, but I'm guessing it'll be `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Select`.
- Override `_prepareOptions` and add an [associative sort](https://www.php.net/asort) like this: `asort($options);` right above `foreach ($options as  $value => $label) {`

**Method Two: New Source Model**

This method will actually change the order of the options anywhere they are requested, front-end or back-end.

- See a generic example of creating an attribute source model [here](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-create-custom-attribute-source-type/).
- Again, make sure that you're extending the right class for your attribute, but I would guess that it will be `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract`
- Override `getAllOptions()` and sort `$this->_options`. Just remember that `$this->_options` isn't a bunch of key/value pairs, it's full of value/label sub-arrays. So you'll either need to build a custom method for [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) or you'll need to build a simple key/value array, `asort` it, and then rebuild the value/label style array.